# Aligning two equations using amsmath, with multiple points of reference

Tags: amsmath, arrays

I'm trying to align two lines of equation, one consisting of words to provide meaning and the one below with numerical values.

```
Number per Second &= Bit Amount &* Rate of Channel &* No. of Chan. \\    

176400 &= 16 &* 44100 &* 2
```

[image]
I've looked at the align documentation and inserted &'s at various points, yet the alignment is not correct. How can I align on the operators to allow the reader to see the word description (e.g. Bit Amount), and then look directly underneath to see the numerical value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ c *{3}{ >{{}}c<{{}} c } }
\text{Number of bits per second} &=&
\text{Bit depth} &\cdot&
\text{Channel rate} &\cdot&
\text{Number of channels} \\
  176\,40    &=&    16       &\cdot&   44\,100   &\cdot&     2
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I dislike very much long verbose pseudoformulas; better to use variables and explain them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ c *{3}{ >{{}}c<{{}} c } }
\mathit{Bps} &=& \mathit{BD} &\cdot& \mathit{CR} &\cdot& \mathit{NC} \\
  176\,40    &=&    16       &\cdot&   44\,100   &\cdot&     2
\end{array}
\\
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{rl@{\qquad}rl}
$\mathit{Bps}={}$ & Number of bits per second &
$\mathit{BD}={}$  & Bit depth \\
$\mathit{CR}={}$  & Channel rate &
$\mathit{NC}={}$  & Number of channels
\end{tabular}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 16 * 44100 Hz * 2 = 1411200 Hz. Also the units are missing (package `siunitx`). Either Bps and CR with Hz; or Bps with bits per second, BD with bits and CR with Hz (s⁻¹).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a completely different approach -- one which uses `\underbrace` directives. (And don't use `*` to indicate multiplication; use either `\times` or `\cdot` instead.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\newcommand\vp{\vphantom{p}}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\text{Number per Bits per Second}}_{176400} = 
\underbrace{\text{Bit Depth}}_{2} \times  
\underbrace{\text{Channel Rate\vp}}_{44100} \times 
\underbrace{\text{Number of Channels\vp}}_{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you must replicate the "look" of screenshot you posted, I think it's easier to do so via a `\tabular` environment. The material to the left of the `=` symbol is right-aligned, whereas the elements to the right of `=` are centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,geometry}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{${}}c<{{}$}} % for binary and relational operator symbols
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{rCcCcCc}
Number per Bits per Second & = & 
Bit Depth                  & \times &
Channel Rate               & \times & 
Number of Channels\\[1ex]
176400 & = & 2 & \times & 44100 & \times & 2
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

with use of `alignat` math environment from  `amsmath` package is not difficult:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\text{Number per Second}
    &= \text{Bit Amount} &* \text{Rate of Channel} &* \text{No. of Chan.} \\
176400 &= 16 &* 44100 &* 2
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```